# Template Classes and methods in C++

Tags: c++, templates, binary-tree

I have been using C# for about a year now, I am attempting to move on to C++ in visual studio. Anyway I am trying to make a generic binary tree in C++ and have run into a few compile errors which I cannot seem to fix.

Initial research seemed to point towards putting the class template inside the header file, yet this gave me a host of other errors.

Some advice from someone with a bit more experience would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the code so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TreeNode<int> IntTree(1, TreeNode<int>(1), TreeNode<int>(2));
    cout << IntTree.toString() << endl;
    return 0;
}


template<class TData> class TreeNode
{

private:
    TData Data;
    TreeNode<TData>& Left;
    TreeNode<TData>& Right;

    void setData(TData data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

public:
    TreeNode<TData>(TData data)
    {
        setData(data);
    }

    TreeNode<TData>(TData data, TreeNode<TData> leftNode, TreeNode<TData> rightNode)
    {
        setData(data);
        setLeft(leftNode);
        setRight(rightNode);
    }

    void setLeft(TreeNode<TData>& leftNode)
    {
        Left = leftNode;
    }

    void setRight(TreeNode<TData>& rightNode)
    {
        Right = rightNode;
    }

    TreeNode<TData>& getLeft()
    {
        return Left;
    }

    TreeNode<TData>& getRight()
    {
        return Right;
    }

    TData& getData()
    {
        return &Data;
    }

    string toString()
    {
        return Left->toString() + Data + Right->toString();
    }
};
```

> ```
> error C2228: left of '.toString' must have class/struct/union.
> error C2065: 'TreeNode' : undeclared identifier.
> error C2065: 'IntTree' : undeclared identifier
> error C2062: type 'int' unexpected.
> ```

Comment: C++ does not have generics, it has templates.

Comment: You declaration of TreeNode needs to come before `main()`.  C++ uses a single pass compiler so if there isn't something saying what a TreeNode is when the compiler first finds it it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the technical explanation as I can now understand what the purpose of a forward declaration is or even better remember to declare all types above the main method.

Comment: @Mgetz Generic refers to the concept of `Generic Programming` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming . Template is C++'s implementation to that concept.

Comment: @texasbruce Thanks, I was so confused really. That's why I took the time to point out that C++ does not have generics. And more to the point that they don't behave anything like C# generics like the OP might have been expecting.

Comment: Your `toString()` method isn't going to work. `int` is not convertible to `std::string()`. You class will only work on types which are implicitly convertible to `std::string()` or for which some form of `std::string operator+( std::string, TData )` operator overload is defined. 

It doesn't appear that you know enough about the basics of C++ to do this yet. C++ is very different from C#.

Comment: I have tackled this one with the to_string method.

Comment: Also the setLeft and setRight methods are probably not doing what you expect them to do. In C++, references cannot be re-assigned to "point" to another object. Instead, the assignment will overwrite the content, which is unitialized in the constructor.

Comment: It is good custom to pass object which are not modified as const& instead of &. Also, what is the value of Left and Right after the TreeNode<TData>(TData data) finished? And this constructor (and the other ones) should take data as const& (or move it).

Answer (score 2):

At the point of usage in your `_tmain()` `TreeNode<>` isn't yet declared.

You must put the complete template class declaration/definition before `_tmain()`, or even better put it in a separate header file, and include that.

Comment: Adding a forward declaration doesn't work. You will need to the complete class definition before `_tmain()`.

Comment: @RSahu You are right, a forward declaration doesn't help. I have fixed this.